# Square up retrieve merchant Id service endpoint not working as expected?

Tags: curl, square-connect

According to documentation at square up, I should be able to retrieve a merchant id with a simple request through curl after getting a personal access token. However, I am getting an error. How can I get a merchant id instead of an exception?

From https://docs.connect.squareup.com:

> Now you can use your personal access token to send your first request to the Connect API.
>
> Open a terminal window and run the following curl command, providing your personal access token where indicated:
>
> ```
> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me
> ```

Expected result in docs:

> ```
> {
>   "id": "JGHJ0343",
>   "name": "Dave Davis",
>   "email": "dave@example.com",
>   "country_code": "US",
>   "language_code": "en-US",
>   "business_name": "Dave's Milkshakes",
>   "business_address": {
>     "address_line_1": "1455 Market St",
>     "locality": "San Francisco",
>     "administrative_district_level_1": "CA",
>     "postal_code": "94103"
>   },
>   "business_phone": {
>     "calling_code": "+1",
>     "number": "4155551234"
>   },
>   "business_type": "restaurants",
>   "account_type": "LOCATION"
> }
> ```

[image: screenshot of exception in PowerShell]

Exception text:

```
PS C:\Users\JMCC> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary".
...
```

Comment: You've edited the screenshot out of your question, so that now it can't possibly be useful to anyone else. However, the comment history can still be seen in the diff, so your personal access token is still public. You need to generate a new personal access token, which will make the old one invalid.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to regenerate your personal access token, as you've posted it in a public forum. You can do that in your developer dashboard at connect.squareup.com.

Second, the documentation assumes you're using a machine with the [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command line program installed. This is a common utility on Linux, Mac, and other UNIX-like machines. Apparently, Microsoft has set up `curl` as an alias for the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) cmdlet in newer versions of PowerShell. I'm not sure why they decided to do this, as the arguments for that command are not compatible with the ones curl provides.

I would recommend getting the win64 version of cURL on the [cURL download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Comment: is there an answer for how to accomplish this using the method the OP identified?

Comment: @driz I assume you mean `Invoke-RestMethod`? If so, I'm sure you can do it but you'll need to translate the options to match, based on the PowerShell documentation I linked. Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows machine to test this on, but something like this might work:

`Invoke-RestMethod https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"}`

Comment: It appears to me to be an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`, not `Invoke-RestMethod`: 
    > get-alias curl
    CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
    -----------     ----                                               ----------
    Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Not sure why I wrote that. At any rate, both commands appear to be very similar.